# NSWindow shows an icon with the window path; how can I remove it?

Tags: cocoa

The title explains my problem.
Here there are two images:

#### Icon

http://cl.ly/ACYq/icon.png

#### The path when I click the icon

http://cl.ly/ABMM/icon2.png

What have I done to set this?
How can I delete this icon?

Answer (score 2):

If there's an icon, it means your window has a represented URL.

You can use the `setRepresentedURL:` method to change or disable it (passing `nil`).